# What is the best way Reinforcement learning, RNN or others to predict the best action we have to take to maximize sales?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network, reinforcement-learning

I have a dataset composed of few features :

```
customerId, actionDay1, SalesDay1, actionDay20, SalesDay20, actionDay30, salesDay30.
```

action can be :

- call
- email
- face 2 face
- nothing

sales :
amount of sales in $

my goal here is to predict the best action we have to take in any day (1, 20 or 30) to sale more.

some customer prefers email, some prefer to be called every time, some others prefer to not be contacted to buy.

the pattern is different for each customer.
my first thought was to apply reinforcement learning for this problem, but I found some difficulty to do the right environment, but also the reward function. a reinforcement learning would work without data and the model will be different for each customer. I would like to have a model that can approximate the behavior of all customers using the dataset I have.

does anyone have an idea on how I can approach this problem using reinforcement learning or something different like Recurrent Neural Net?

Comment: There is also [data science stack Exchange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/) which might be of your interest.

Answer (score 0):

Reinforcement Learning would be a challenge for you to use at this moment. Especially if you are looking to just throw data into a Neural Network expecting results. RL even when implemented well will fail at times due to numerous reasons related to stochastic that or the agent discovered an exploit/flaw in your code and is now maximizing its reward gain and --- tl;dr RL tends to be a smartass.

Start off by setting a baseline with a multilayer perceptron (MLP).

The field is empirical in nature so setup a process to experiment properly:

State your problem.
Gather data.
Clean data.
Run the data through common algorithms for your problem.
Check results.
Study and work to improve your results.
Present results to client.